# How to set several specific locations in Google Map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary, location

I want to make an android application for bicycle stations in Tehran. For that I need to show specific and static locations on the map like this:

[image: google map locations example]

I tried several libraries from Github but didn't work. I also added an extra location `(double latitude1 = 35.747394; double longitude1 = 51.267577;)` but the location mark doesn't appear on the map.

I'd appreciate if anyone could help me.

This is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.playpersia.bicyclemap.R;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;



public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    double latitude1 = 35.747394;
    double longitude1 = 51.267577;
    // Google Map
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:35.694677, 51.394871");
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); //***Change Here***
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(mapIntent);
            finish();

        }

        try {

            initilizeMap();


            MarkerOptions markerOptions1 = new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1)).title("بوستان جوانمردان");

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @
    Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

    private void initilizeMap() {

        if (googleMap == null) {
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map));

            if (googleMap != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "خطا", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is is exactly the problem? you can't add several marker? or the map is not showing ? , looking at your code i see that you are adding just one marker

Comment: @youzking yeah I just added one location but it doesn't show that one location

Comment: adding a marker is note suffisant you have to move the camera of the map to the added marker, your marker ma be added but it is just not visible, try adding this after adding the marker :
`LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);`

Comment: it didn't work@youzking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) documentation. It allows you to query for place information on a variety of categories, such as: establishments, prominent points of interest, geographic locations, and more. You can search for places either by proximity or a text string.

Use [Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) which lets you search for places within a specified area. You can refine your search request by supplying keywords or specifying the type of place you are searching for. Here is the [list of supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).

> Sample HTTP URL of the following form:
>
> `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/output?parameters`
>
> where `output` may be either of the following values:
>
> - `json` (recommended) indicates output in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)
> - `xml` indicates output as XML

The following example is a search request for places of type 'transit_station' within a 500m radius of a point in Sydney, Australia:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&type=transit_station&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Check these related links and [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/showing-nearby-places-using-google-places-api-and-google-map-android-api-v2/):

- [Finding nearest locations using Google Maps API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16561296/finding-nearest-locations-using-google-map-api)
- [How to hide/show groups of markers by category with Google Maps in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006206/how-to-hide-show-groups-of-markers-by-category-with-google-maps-in-android)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I used the tutorial link and it solved my problem
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to show map in your app itself.You would have found the mistake if you read your log cat. googleMap variable isn't initialised. So if add marker it will throw null pointer exception. you should use getMapAsync callback to initialise googleMap variable then you can add markers.This will work if your map shows and adding Marker isn't working. If map is not showing the problem with api key. correct that and and remove intent code and try this.

Comment: I corrected the api key, now it gives me this error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)' on a null object reference
07-24 21:40:04.931 19095-19095/com.playpersia.bicyclemap