# Display specific markers based on spinner

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to display specific markers depending on the selected value of the `Spinner`

Here is my `MainActviity`  :

```
package com.maasin.map.ret1;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.maasin.map.ret1.m_FireBase.FirebaseHelper;
import com.maasin.map.ret1.m_Model.Spacecraft;
import com.maasin.map.ret1.m_Model.*;
import com.maasin.map.ret1.m_UI.MyAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static com.maasin.map.ret1.R.layout.map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {


    Spinner spinnerDropdown;
    // DatabaseReference db;
    Boolean saved = null;
    ArrayList < Spacecraft > spacecrafts = new ArrayList < > ();
    //   private FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference db;
    FirebaseHelper helper;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView rv;
    EditText nameEditTxt, propTxt, descTxt;
    String filter = "";
    String route = "";

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

    DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = database.getReference();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter spinneradapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerDropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinnerDropdown.setAdapter(spinneradapter);

        spinnerDropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);


        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("           The MasTrans APP");

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        String size = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //SETUP RECYCLER
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //INITIALIZE FIREBASE DB
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        helper = new FirebaseHelper(db);
        //ADAPTER
        adapter = new MyAdapter(this, helper.retrieve());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);


        Button fab = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                adapter = new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, retrieve());
                rv.setAdapter(adapter);


            }

            ;
        });
        helper.s(size);


    }


    public Boolean save(Spacecraft spacecraft) {
        if (spacecraft == null) {
            saved = false;
        } else {
            try {
                db.child("Spacecraft").push().setValue(spacecraft);
                saved = true;
            } catch (DatabaseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                saved = false;
            }
        }
        return saved;
    }

    //IMPLEMENT FETCH DATA AND FILL ARRAYLIST
    private void fetchData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)

    {

        spacecrafts.clear();
        for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


            Spacecraft spacecraft = ds.getValue(Spacecraft.class);


            spacecrafts.add(spacecraft);
        }
    }


    public ArrayList < Spacecraft > retrieve() {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        final DatabaseReference establishments = database.getReference("vehicles");


        establishments.orderByChild(route).equalTo(filter).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        return spacecrafts;

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        TextView spinnerDialogText = (TextView) view;
        filter = spinnerDialogText.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("filter", filter);

        if (filter.equals("Bato")) {
            route = "Route001";

        } else if (filter.equals("Hilongos")) {

            route = "Route002";

        } else if (filter.equals("Baybay")) {

            route = "Route003";

        } else if (filter.equals("Ormoc")) {

            route = "Route004";

        } else if (filter.equals("Mahaplag")) {

            route = "Route005";

        } else if (filter.equals("Abuyog")) {

            route = "Route006";

        } else if (filter.equals("Palo")) {

            route = "Route007";

        } else if (filter.equals("Tacloban")) {

            route = "Route008";

        } else if (filter.equals("Macrohon")) {

            route = "Route009";

        } else if (filter.equals("Padre Burgos")) {

            route = "Route010";

        } else if (filter.equals("Malitbog")) {

            route = "Route011";

        } else if (filter.equals("Sogod")) {

            route = "Route012";

        } else if (filter.equals("Himay-angan")) {

            route = "Route13";

        } else if (filter.equals("Liloan")) {

            route = "Route014";

        } else if (filter.equals("San Ricardo")) {

            route = "Route015";

        } else if (filter.equals("Benit")) {

            route = "Route016";

        } else if (filter.equals("Saint Bernard")) {

            route = "Route017";

        } else if (filter.equals("San Juan")) {

            route = "Route018";

        } else if (filter.equals("Hinunangan")) {

            route = "Route019";
        } else if (filter.equals("Silago")) {

            route = "Route020";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent) {

    }
}
```

Here is my code for `MapsActivity` :

```
package com.maasin.map.ret1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private String routes;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        Intent i = this.getIntent();

        routes = i.getStringExtra("filter");
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;


        LatLng Maasin = new LatLng(10.132188, 124.834808);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Maasin).title("Maasin City Bus Terminal"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Maasin));


        LatLng Bato = new LatLng(10.340038, 124.849840);

        if (routes.equals("Bato")) {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Bato).title("Bato"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be easy.  Here is a solution using different Markers for checkboxes, you should be able to easily change it to be based on a spinner: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006206/how-to-hide-show-groups-of-markers-by-category-with-google-maps-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the help, but specifically i have want to view two markers. My fixed marker which is "Maasin" and the selected value of my spinner

Comment: You should still be able to use the answer there as a guide. It's not hard.