# Android marker setVisible(false) didn't works

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm tring to show/hide marker depending on its location.

```
LatLng LocDon = new LatLng(latitude_don, longitude_don);
        Marker mk1 = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(LocDon)  
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    allMarkerMap.put(mk1, Don.class);
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
    mk1.setVisible(false);

if(r>=longitude_don&&_r<=longitude_don){
        if(l>=latitude_don&&_l<=latitude_don){
            don = don + 1;
            if(don < 2) {
                vibe.vibrate(200);
                mk1.setVisible(true);                    
            }
        }
     }

    if(r<longitude_don||_r>longitude_don){
        if(l<latitude_don||_l>latitude_don) {
            mk1.setVisible(false);
            vibe.vibrate(1000);
        }
    }
```

I put two type of vibration to check getting in the if sentence.
I can get two type of `vibration(200&1000)` but only I can't hide marker.
Most of answer for these kind of question(hiding marker), people say that using `setVisible(false).` But why I can't get it? is there anybody help me... Please....

Edited.
add log.

03-27 21:58:06.719 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 610K, 10% free 41281K/45652K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 39ms
03-27 21:58:11.624 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off
03-27 21:58:11.654 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off
03-27 21:58:11.694 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 330K, 10% free 41286K/45652K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 40ms
03-27 21:58:16.809 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off
03-27 21:58:16.839 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off
03-27 21:58:16.889 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 141K, 10% free 41332K/45652K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 47ms
03-27 21:58:21.733 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 165K, 10% free 41340K/45652K, paused 6ms+6ms, total 63ms
03-27 21:58:25.677 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 160K, 10% free 41387K/45652K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 75ms
03-27 21:58:30.672 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 198K, 10% free 41408K/45652K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 45ms
03-27 21:58:36.608 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 146K, 10% free 41452K/45652K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 37ms
03-27 21:58:46.558 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Entered: ON
03-27 21:58:46.608 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 832K, 10% free 41492K/45652K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 41ms
03-27 21:58:46.648 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Entered: ON
03-27 21:58:56.637 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 381K, 9% free 41759K/45652K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 37ms
03-27 21:58:58.870 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 157K, 9% free 41803K/45652K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 35ms
03-27 21:59:03.684 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 261K, 9% free 41696K/45652K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 47ms
03-27 21:59:07.628 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 141K, 9% free 41742K/45652K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 63ms
03-27 21:59:09.680 30659-30666/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/dalvikvm: Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
03-27 21:59:12.683 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 173K, 9% free 41751K/45652K, paused 6ms+5ms, total 48ms
03-27 21:59:14.795 30659-30803/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 140K, 9% free 41797K/45652K, paused 7ms+6ms, total 97ms
03-27 21:59:17.728 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 117K, 9% free 41831K/45652K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 35ms
03-27 21:59:23.744 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 173K, 9% free 41842K/45652K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 35ms
03-27 21:59:27.728 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 173K, 9% free 41857K/45652K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 42ms
03-27 21:59:31.682 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 135K, 9% free 41904K/45652K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 49ms
03-27 21:59:38.588 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off
03-27 21:59:38.699 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung D/dalvikvm: GC_EXPLICIT freed 157K, 9% free 41927K/45652K, paused 5ms+8ms, total 62ms
03-27 21:59:38.699 30659-30659/org.androidtown.realchangdeokgung I/Exited: Off

Comment: try using  `mk1.remove()`...

Comment: Please look at this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507821/is-it-possible-to-show-hide-markers-in-android-google-maps-api-v2 hope it help you.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Thank you but it didn't works...

Comment: check if your code enters in second if condition..

Comment: @ManpreetSingh Thank you, but I'm not sure what is different marker.remove() or marker.setVisible(false) and your links... it looks same to me... If I was wrong please some hints for that...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 what does it mean, "your code enters in second". I cant' get it... Sorry....

Comment: print a log in condtion: `if(l<latitude_don||_l>latitude_don) {
            Log.i("Entered","ON");
            mk1.setVisible(false);;
            vibe.vibrate(1000);
        }`

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 Thank you for your help... I tried but it didn't looks different when it gets to enter the marker and exit the marker... Which is my mistake.............

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/43047322/7399521

Answer (score -1):

**use any one its usefull**

```
marker.remove();
```

**or**

```
googlemap.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to remain other marker and only remove the marker. So I can't use map.clear. Also marker.remove() didn't work.... hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm........................

Comment: i think your marker not get map instance... can you please show your full code... becoz clear some bugs @dalami0i