# How to properly hide markers in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to add a bunch of markers to a map with show/hide buttons for each category of markers. Adding a marker from stored db data puts them on the map and makes them clickable, but they won't respond to setMap(null) unless that call is through google.event.addListener(marker, ...). Calling it from a standard js button onclick event, or via google.event.addDomListener(marker, ...) doesn't work.

Also maybe helpful to note is that when I call marker.setAnimation(BOUNCE) the marker starts bouncing but it looks like there is a duplicate marker under it. Similarly, if I drag the marker it's as if an unmovable duplicate is created right under it.

Thoughts? This is super frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

Just like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12905956/306921) ? Are you trying to avoid google maps api's `google.maps.event.addDomListener`? Why? You can use it to listen to your button's click event too. just as in:

```
var YourButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

function HideMarkers() {
  // Hide us
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(YourButton, 'click', HideMarkers);
```

customized for you [from](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-domListener). For the second part, seeming like double markers I suppose we need some code..

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wasn't trying to avoid addDomListener, I just meant that using it didn't seem to help my problem. The function seems like a great way to avoid having to include query in the page. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be purely user error. I am using firebase to store map data without a server backend and was adding duplicate markers. This explains the "inability to hide" and also the appearance of duplicate markers when dragging or animating.

The reason it was working from a click event on the marker was that both duplicate markers were receiving the click event and so both were being hidden.

setMap appears to be perfectly reliable when used in or out of google event handlers.